# Is there any algorithm to achieve some optimization for hanger placement?

Tags: algorithm

I need to do a job where I need to place a particular object(Hanger) in a standard distance.

The rules are:

- We should try to place each object in a given standard distance from each other.
- There is a max distance from one object to adjacent object which in no way should be violated.
- From the start and end also similar standard and maximum distance rule applies.
- And there are some portions given where the objects placement needs to be avoided.

I'm not even able to start... which algorithm to use.
If anyone has any suggestion how I can achieve this or some related source please let me know.

[image]

Comment: How many hangers ? (The questions says one !) Optimize what ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust sorry that should be hangers/objects(Edited the mistake).
The number will be dependent on the input values like total placement length and following the given rules.

Comment: Use basic math? 10 hangers for 44 inches of space: 40/(10+1) = 4 inches apart with 2 inches of space on either end. 10 hangers with a max distance of 4 inches for 60 inches of space? Use the first 44 inches. If you have places that need to be avoided, subtract those from the total available distance. Etc.

Comment: *there are some portions given where the objects placement needs to be avoided* What are those restrictions? It 's impossible to give you suggestions when we don't know all the rules of the game. Please provide a complete and detailed description of the problem.

Comment: @user8630414 Are your criteria: 1) Never place hangars farther than max_distance apart. 2) Avoid forbidden areas unless doing so violates (1). 3) Attempt to place hangars standard_distance apart unless doing so violates (1) or (2). 4) Treat the end points as if they were hangars for purposes of rules 1-3.

Comment: @Dave

1. The maxDistance is the ultimate hard rule here which should never get violated.
2. Then try Avoid forbidden area.
3. Then try to get hanger to hanger distance on or closer to the standard length.
4. Try to place less/minimum possible number of hangers in total.

Rule priority order 1st>2>3>4th.